# Combining SUMIF and SUBTOTAL

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have looked at each of the other posts regarding combining these two functions, but I don't understand them enough to apply them to my specific task.  I have to manually create an AR aging for a small customer of ours.

I have a workbook with 4 tabs.  One for each of their customers (3) and one for a summary.  Each month, I add the new invoices and paid invoices.  Then I match invoice to payment and hide the lines.  Based the due date, I have a column with the AR aging labels (Current, <30, <60, <90, <120).

In the summary worksheet, I have a table to generate the report.

I have the customer names across the top row.  Down the left side I have the Labels (Current, 30, etc). Currently, I manually sum the rows that match the Aging category.  But I want to be able to automatically do the adding.

I know how to use the SUMIF function and I know how to use the SUBTOTAL function to ignore hidden rows.  But I cannot seem to get the two to work together.

I have tried following the examples giving in the other posts, but they all seem to work in one worksheet and so I get confused.  Please help!

Comment: Sounds like a job for a Pivot Table.

Comment: I suspect that my comment is similar (at least in spirit) to what Deliverance is saying (except I’m not sure I understand 100% what he or she is saying).  I believe that your problem really lies in the fact that you are *manually* hiding rows for invoices.  I suggest that you add a column wherein you mark paid invoices.  You can then use this column both to hide those invoices (on Sheets 1-3) and as a criterion in `SUMIFS` functions on Sheet4.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Kyle. Maybe with a helper row which has an IF statement which could state, "paid" if balance is 0, or "fully due" if no payments received, or "partial due" if underpaid, or "credit due" if overpaid. And another with a date formula for days past due.

I think we'd all need to see a sample file to help further.